# Desktop icons larger than 128px

Tags: macos, osx-lion, icons, desktop

I'm wondering if there's a way to break the limit of 128px for desktop icons in OSX Lion 10.7 (I have 10.7.5) by hacking some system files?

Comment: The setting is stored in `/Users/danielbeck/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`, but values greater than 128 are displayed as 128px.

Comment: `tell application "Finder" to set icon size of icon view options of window of desktop to 200` didn't work either.

Comment: @DanielBeck I know, back in Leopard that used to work but not in Lion

Comment: Maybe you can get the TotalFinder developers to add this as a feature.

Comment: Ok but still there should be a way to do it without totalFinder